# Adjusting a photo so it matches another photo's colors in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I often have to stitch together 2 photos and make the edges match. E.g. if the photos have different lighting, I have to manually tweak the photos. What I would like to do is select 1 pixel from each photo and have Photoshop transform one of the photos so that the 1 pixel matches the other photo's pixel.

E.g. if a pixel in one photo is 10% brighter than a pixel in the second photo, Photoshop will make the entire second photo 10% brighter.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the image adjustmet Match color . The key areas can be selected freely.

NOTE  you should use manual exposure and color balance to get well mergeable photos. The automatic processing in the camera can be non-linear and cause different color structures because only good looks is thought by the  camera maker.